# An $R$-division ring $(\mathcal{D},\varphi)$ is epic iff the division closure of $\varphi(R)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ is $\mathcal{D}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am studying non commuatitve ring theory and I'm having problems with the following exercise:

**Let $R$ be a ring and $(\mathcal{D},\varphi)$ an $R$-division ring. Then, $(\mathcal{D},\varphi)$ is epic  iff the division closure of $\varphi(R)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ is $\mathcal{D}$.**

First of all let us fix some definitions and notations:

Let $R$ be a ring. An $R$-ring is a pair $(S,\varphi)$, where $S$ is a ring and $\varphi:R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism. Moreover, if $S$ is a division ring we say that it is a $R$-division ring.

Let $R$ be a ring. An $R$-ring $(S,\varphi)$ is epic if for any ring $S'$ and maps $\psi,\psi':S\to S'$ such that $\psi\circ\varphi=\psi'\circ\varphi$ then $\psi=\psi'$.

Let $R$ be a ring and $(S,\varphi)$ an $R$-ring. The domain of $\varphi$ is defined as:
$$\text{dom}(\varphi)=\lbrace s\in S\mid \forall\text{ ring }S'\text{ and }\psi,\psi':S\to S'\text{ such that }\psi\circ\varphi=\psi'\circ\varphi\text{ then }\psi(s)=\psi'(s)\rbrace$$

Hence it is immediate to notice that $\text{dom}(\varphi)=S$ iff $(S,\varphi)$ is epic.

Now, I have the following lemma:

Let $R$ be a ring and $(S,\varphi)$ an  $R$-ring, the following are equivalent:

- $x\in\text{dom}(\varphi)$.
- For every $S$-bimodule $M$ and $\forall~y\in M$ such that $ry=yr$ for all $r\in\varphi(R)$ it holds that $xy=yx$.
- $1\otimes_{R} x=x \otimes_{R} 1$.
- For every right $S$-bimodules $M$ and $N$ and $\psi\in\text{Hom}_R(M,N)$ it holds that $\psi(yx)=\psi(y)x~\forall~ y\in M$.

What I want to do is to use this lemma to solve the exercise.

I was able to do one of the implications:

If the division closure of $\varphi(R)$ is $\mathcal{D}$ and $0\neq s\in \text{dom}(\varphi)$ then:
$$s^{-1} \otimes_{R} 1=s^{-1} \otimes_{R} ss^{-1}=s^{-1}s \otimes_{R} s^{-1}=1 \otimes_{R} s^{-1}$$  and since  by the previous lema we have:    $$\text{dom}(\varphi)=\lbrace s\in S\mid 1\otimes_{R} s=s \otimes_{R} 1\rbrace$$
this implies that $\text{dom}(\varphi)=\mathcal{D}$ and so $(\mathcal{D},\varphi)$ is epic.

But I dont know how to do the other implication. If you can check whether my first implication is good and help me with the other one I would be very grateful

Comment: If $0\neq s\in$dom$(\varphi)$, then $\psi(s^{-1})=\psi(s^{-1})\psi'(s)\psi'(s^{-1})=\psi(s^{-1})\psi(s)\psi'(s^{-1})=\psi'(s^{-1})$.

Comment: @tkf Thanks, but you proved the same implication I have already done, right?

Comment: @tkf also $\psi$ and $\psi'$ are not homomorphisms, so I don't see why this is true.

Comment: Yes - just another way of showing what you have already done (hence a comment rather than an answer).  By 'map' do you not mean ring homomorphism?

Comment: @tkf no, sorry for the misleading, this is why I don't think you can avoid the lema to prove it. I would be very suprised if you can prove it directly. But thanks for your time, I edit the post.

Comment: But then let $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, and we have maps $\psi,\psi'\colon \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$, where $\psi$ is the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$, whilst $\psi'$ restricts to the identity on $\mathbb{Z}$, and is $0$ elsewhere.  Then $\psi\neq\psi'$.

Comment: @tkf right, then my teacher was wromg, since he said that they need not be homomorphisms... Thanks for your correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the division closure of $\varphi(R)$ in $S$. In order to complete the exercise, assuming the given lemma, you must show that if $x\notin T$, then $x\otimes_R 1\neq 1\otimes_R x$ in $S\otimes_R S$.

Suppose $a,b,c\in S$ satisfy for all $s\in S$: $$sa\otimes_R s'=s\otimes_R as',\qquad sb\otimes_R s'=s\otimes_R bs',\qquad sc\otimes_R s'=s\otimes_R cs',$$
and $c\neq 0$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
sab\otimes_R s'&=&sa\otimes_R bs'=s\otimes_R abs',\\
s(a+b)\otimes_R s'&=&sa\otimes_R s'+sb\otimes_R s'=s\otimes_R as'+s\otimes_R bs'=s\otimes_R (a+b)s',\\
sc^{-1}\otimes_Rs'&=&sc^{-1}\otimes_R cc^{-1}s'=sc^{-1}c\otimes_R c^{-1}s'=s\otimes_R c^{-1}s'.
\end{eqnarray*}

For any $r\in \varphi(R)$ we have $sr\otimes_R s'=s\otimes_R rs'$ and this property is preserved by addition, multiplication, and taking inverses, so  for any $t\in T$ we have $st\otimes_R s'=s\otimes_R ts'$.

We conclude $$S\otimes_R S=S\otimes_T S.$$

Now $S$ has a basis $\{e_i|\,\, i\in I\}$ as a right module over $T$ and a basis $\{f_j|\,\, j\in J\}$ as a left module over $T$, where we may assume that for some $i_0\in I$ and $j_0\in J$ we have $e_i=f_j=1$.  As $T$ is by construction a division ring, the proof is identical to the usual proof that [every vector space has a basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Proof_that_every_vector_space_has_a_basis) via Zorn's lemma.

We next define a function $$\Theta\colon S\otimes_T S\to {\rm Hom}_{\rm Set}(I\times J, T),$$ by
$$\Theta\left(\sum_k s_k\otimes_T s'_k\right)(i,j) = \sum_k e^i (s_k)f^j( s'_k), 
$$
where $\{e^r|\,\,r\in I\}$ is the dual set of right $T$-linear maps $S\to T$ to the basis $\{e_r|\,\,r\in I\}$ and similarly $\{f^r|\,\,r\in J\}$ is the dual set of left $T$-linear maps $S\to T$ to the basis $\{f_r|\,\,r\in I\}$.

We must check that $\Theta$ is well defined.  At present it is only well defined if we abuse notation and regard the sum of tensor products as a set of pairs of elements of $S$.  For $s,s_1,s_2,s',s_1',s_2'\in S$ and $t\in T$ we have: \begin{eqnarray*}
\Theta((s_1+s_2)\otimes_T s')(i,j)&=&\Theta(s_1\otimes_T s')(i,j)+\Theta(s_2\otimes_T s')(i,j)=\Theta(s_1\otimes_T s'+s_2\otimes_T s')(i,j),\\\\
\Theta(s\otimes_T (s_1'+s_2'))(i,j)&=&\Theta(s\otimes_T s_1')(i,j)+\Theta(s\otimes_T s_2')(i,j)=\Theta(s\otimes_T s_1'+s\otimes_T s_2')(i,j),\\\\
\Theta(st\otimes_T s')(i,j)&=&e^i(st)f^j(s')=e^i(s)tf^j(s')=e^i(s)f^j(ts')=\Theta(s\otimes_T ts').
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $\Theta$ is well defined on $S\otimes_T S$, and we may stop abusing notation.

For $w\in S\otimes_T S$, let the *support* of $\Theta(w)$ be the set: $$\{(i,j)\in I\times J|\,\, \Theta(w)(i,j)\neq 0\}.$$

Now suppose $x\notin T$.  Then the support of $\Theta(x\otimes_T 1)$ consists only of elements of the form $(i,j_0)$ including ones where $i\neq i_0$.  On the other hand the support of $\Theta(1\otimes_T x)$ consists only of elements of the form $(i_0,j)$ including ones where $j\neq j_0$.

Thus we have $$x\otimes_T 1\neq 1\otimes_T x,$$
and
$$x\otimes_R 1\neq 1\otimes_R x,$$
as required.

Comment: Very nice, love your proof and you were very clear. Thanks :)